# Script that input files starting with dash and has space in center

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a shell script that converts a .md file to .pdf using pandoc.

When executing the script for example:

> ./script *file.md

it doesn't detect the files needed to be converted because they resemble this:

> -first-file.md
>
> second _ file.md

First one starts with a dash. Second one had an underscore in between spaces in the center.

Comment: You need to include the part of your script that fails with those filenames. The first example can be a bit more difficult, but the second filename is easily handled with proper quoting.

Comment: oh I actually solved it. a simple ./ was needed.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that the script uses the filename of the file in such a way that its name is being interpreted as a set of options to some utility, as in

```
rm "$filename"
```

when `$filename` starts with a dash.

There are two ways of making sure that the command executes correctly whenever a pathname may start with a dash:

1. Make sure that the pathname *does not start with a dash*, for example by including an absolute or relative path.  If a file in the current directory is to be removed with `rm "$filename"`, then make sure that `$filename` starts with `./`.  This is usually matter of changing a loop from

   ```
   for filename in some-pattern; do
   ```

   into

   ```
   for filename in ./some-pattern; do
   ```
2. Use `--` to signal the end of command line options to the utility, as in

   ```
   rm -- "$filename"
   ```

   The parsing of options on the command line will stop at the `--` and all the later arguments will be taken as operands to the utility rather than as possible options.  This is a good solution when you are receiving a pathname from the user on the command line and you don't know whether it's given with a path or not.  Note that you can't just prepend `./` to the given pathname as that would make the pathname relative to the current directory, even though the user may have given an absolute path.

Related to filenames containing spaces etc.:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)